# image pattern matching in java

Tags: java, image-processing, pattern-matching

Earlier i was searching for fingerprint recognisation in java, but didn't find anything how to implement. So, now i have decided to just matching the pattern of two images of fingerprint after getting fingerprint manually. And then, compare their pattern. And i think, this can be done by comparing two image and matching their pixel similarity (as per my finding).

So, now i am looking for any API/library/SDK/framework or anything available in Java, for comparing pattern of two images and getting the percentage match between them.

I'll appreciate any idea !!

Comment: This won't work. Rotation, sweat, cuts, etc. all play into recognition. If you don't find a package that is handling all this already, which you might need to pay for, or you don't have the next year and a half to do research, you will fail at this task.

This isn't a statement about you; biometric matching is just really, really hard.

Comment: Stefan is most likely right but see if you can find some documentation on how 2D barcodes are recognized.

Comment: While this task my hard to accomplish, and could take a lot of blood sweat and tears; not to mention time - I don't like the attitude I'm getting here. If we all had the "well I can't find a working code that's already been written, so it must be impossible" attitude, how would anything get done? Sure this is an extremely hard thing to do, but if you what and how to search you can find anything online! Even if there's nothing out there for Java, I can't see why such a program could not be ported...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [WEKA](http://weka.wikispaces.com/). There might be something in there for your needs, but as Stefan Kendall already mentioned it's not easy at all.

Also, http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/ might be useful, but unfortunately there is no java version yet.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, or even properly studied it - but from what I have seen, [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biometricsdk/) project may help you. (Currently it is for Java and .NET):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/biometricsdk/